# How do I change API in cosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a cosmosDB with mongo API, however there are many features not supported in this API so I want to switch to SQL API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As things stand today it is not possible to switch you account from one type to another.

This is what you need to do if you need to switch to the SQL API:

1. Create a SQL API Cosmos DB Account
2. Download the Cosmos DB[migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#MongoDB)
3. Migrate all the data from the MongoDB account to the SQL API account
4. Delete the MongoDB account